# Why do these two methods of loading images from SQL CE into a WPF Image produce different results?

Tags: wpf, sql-server-ce, memorystream, valueconverter

In a `ValueConverter`, I was trying to convert a `System.Data.Linq.Binary` (SQL CE image) to a `BitmapImage`. This method works (image is show correctly on the form):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                                                     CultureInfo culture) {
    Binary binary = value as Binary;
    if (binary != null) {
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(binary.ToArray());
        bitmap.EndInit();
        return bitmap;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method does **NOT** work (but no exception is thrown, strangely):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                                                     CultureInfo culture) {
    Binary binary = value as Binary;
    if (binary != null) {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(binary.ToArray())) {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Good programming practice states that you should dispose of any streams you create... so I'm confused why the second method doesn't work, but the first does. Any insights?

Comment: I have some simpler sample code here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-save-and-retrieve-images-using.html

Comment: Your conversion code from byte[] to Image uses `Image.FromStream(ms);` which appears to be Windows Forms specific (I'm using WPF). I checked `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` and `System.Windows.Controls.Image`, and neither of them had a `FromStream` method. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                                                     CultureInfo culture) {
    Binary binary = value as Binary;
    if (binary != null) {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(binary.ToArray())) {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; 
            bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            bitmap.Freeze(); 
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In your non-working version, your `using` block means the stream is closed *before* the image is actually decoded.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would that when you are disposing the `MemoryStream`, you are nullifying the `StreamSource` of the bitmap. So, when the bitmap tries to render, there is no valid data available.

Comment: but he returns the bitmap before the `MemoryStream` is disposed, doesn't it?

Comment: @VoodooChild, Good point, but is it possible WPF doesn't try to actually render the bitmap until after `Dispose()` has been called?